# Installing Chrome OS on HP Pavilion

Tags: google-chrome, usb-flash-drive, google-chrome-os, hp-pavilion

Trying to install Chrome OS on HP Pavillion tx1000. I changed the BIOS to boot from USB before hard drive, and created a bootable USB drive (SanDisk Cruzer 4GB). No matter how many ways I try to make the USB drive, the laptop hangs on the startup screen, and trying to open the Boot Order Options freezes on "Fixed disk 0: ...".

On the other hand, without the USB plugged in, the computer continues, and displays "Initialized Mouse", and then onto the Boot Order Options. If you let it boot normally from the beginning, it starts up fine into Windows Vista.

I am using Hexxeh's Chrome OS build.

Here are the different methods I've tried for making the Bootable USB Drive:

- Hexxeh's Image Creator (for Mac)
- Making the USB device bootable (using [these](http://www.ehow.com/how_5768596_make-bootable-cruzer-drive.html) directions). I wrote the image using Win32DiskImager.
- Writing the image using Win32DiskImager (without making it bootable).

Comment: Can you verify if the USB drive boots in another machine? So we can figure out if its the drive, maybe something wrong, or something didn't take during its creation. Or maybe its just the laptop.

Comment: I tried booting from the USB on a Mac, with the same result. When booting from it on a Mac, I held ALT during boot up, but it still didn't work.

Comment: What version of Hexxeh you used? It might be that the image is broken and/or your hardware is not supported.

Comment: Maybe try using another bootable USB utility altogether? Like pendrivelinux.com?

Comment: I tried Vanilla and Lime builds.

Comment: Are you sure chrome-os support every device in you computer? Maybe one of the device is not supported and stop the booting. 

You can also retry to create a usb-bootable chrome-os.